# Find coordinates of two vector product given each vector in coordinate format

Tags: vectors

$\vec{a} = (-1,0,2), \vec{b} = (3,-1,1), \vec{c} = (2,1,2) $

I need to find coordinates of vectors, as well as modulus of the following:

1) $\vec{a}$ x $\vec{b}$

2) $\vec{b}$ x $\vec{c}$

I am not sure I not understand how to find above.

Should I sum up coordinates to get $\times$? And afterwards take squares to find modulus?

Comment: Use [these formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Computing_the_cross_product) for computing the cross product. And by "module" do you mean "modulus," meaning length?

Comment: Yea he did, he/she accepted my edit. @RoryDaulton

Comment: @renathy See the like Rory (+1 there) has given; it should answer your query.

Comment: @Rory Daulton Would it be for 1) (2,7,1) and module would be sqrt(54)? If yes, please, create an answer, I would mark it as answer.

Comment: Since you know how to do it now, renathy, I'd encourage you to write up and post an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Using formulas given in link by @Rory Daulton

[image]

Thus 
$\vec{a}$ x $\vec{b} = (0+2)i + (6+1)j + (1+0)k = 2i + 7j + 1k $

If you do not remember formula, it could be easier to remember determinant form:

[image]

from where determinant can be calculated using two different formulas:

[image]

or

[image]

Thus $\vec{a}$ x $\vec{b} = (0\times{i} + 6\times{j} + 1\times{k}) - (-2\times{i} - 1\times{j} + 0\times{k})=2{i} + 7{j} + 1{k}$

Modulus can be found as $\sqrt{2\times2 + 7\times7 + 1\times1}=\sqrt{54}$

The very same idea is for $\vec{b}$ x $\vec{c}$, finding
$\vec{a}$ x $\vec{b} = -3i-4j+5k$ and modulus = $\sqrt{42}$

Comment: Hey I know it's a bit harsh but I NEVER remember those formulas, so if you do it as the determinant you'll earn a +1 from me!

Comment: Good. But in the last line you've written $a\times b$ where you meant $b\times c$, and you got the modulus wrong.